# How to hide variables and some functions in a module in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am hobby programmar.Now, am in the middle of making a class library in vb.net. I am making some necessary win32 API functions inside a class library and use it in my hobby projects for ease of use. 
I have a main class and few modules in this project. For easiness, i made each module for each section. For example a window module for window related api declarations and variables and structure. The main class contains only all the wrapper functions. So i am declared the variables and structures and api declarations as public so that i can access them from main class. After i build this class library, i just tested it. But there is a problem. All public vars and structures and declarations are available to access there in my test project. I need to hide those declarations and structures and special vars. They are for internal use. But how to make them hide ? When i declared them as private, i can't access them from my wrapper function in Mainclass. What to do

Comment: "internal use" = `Friend`

Comment: OOps, that's my mistake. I have declared some structures and some vars in the Mainclass too. So it has become available from dll. Now, no problem.